# Creating a new column in R with values from other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subtraction

everyone, I'm trying to create a new column on a previously created dataframe called "corrected_rides", subtracting values from two columns on the same dataframe "ended_at" and "started_at" and reflect the results on the new column "ride_length".

The data of those columns goes like this:

```r
> ended_at           <chr> "2022-12-05 10:56:34", "2022-12-18 07:08:44", "2022-12-13 08:59:51"
> started_at         <chr> "2022-12-05 10:47:18", "2022-12-18 06:42:33", "2022-12-13 08:47:45"
```

I want to substract ended_at from started_at, but I can't see the way. I'm a rookie on R, so expect gross errors.

```r
> Df <- Df %>% Mutate(ride_length = ended_at - started_at)
> Error in Mutate(., ride_length = ended_at - started_at) : 
> could not find function "Mutate"
> Df <- Df %>% mutate(ride_length = ended_at - started_at)
> Error in mutate(., ride_length = ended_at - started_at) : 
> object 'Df' not found
> corrected_rides <- Df %>% mutate(ride_length = ended_at - started_at)
> Error in mutate(., ride_length = ended_at - started_at) : 
> object 'Df' not found
> df %>%
> mutate(ride_length = ended_at - started_at)
> Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
> no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"
```

EDIT 2:

I've cleaned my environment with:rm(list = ls())

Then I proceed to create a new column, entitled "ride_length" with data from other two columns, which will be a substraction from the column "ended_at" to "started_at". The dataframe I'm using is "corrected_rides", which currently has 5674730 rows.

Then, as RYann politely indicated me, I copied his code chunk, which has a tibble.

```
corrected_rides <- tibble(ended_at = c("2022-12-05 10:56:34", "2022-12-18 07:08:44", "2022-12-13 08:59:51"),
             started_at = c("2022-12-05 10:47:18", "2022-12-18 06:42:33", "2022-12-13 08:47:45"))
corrected_rides |> mutate(ride_length = as_datetime(ended_at) - as_datetime(started_at))
```

Then, I've tried to visualize the "ride_length" column ggplot with PLUS another two variants which were in my df "corrected_rides": "casual" and "member". Since I wanted to know which kidn of users uses the "Cycling" system the most. And this is my code:

```
ggplot(data = ride_length) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = "member_casual", y = "duration_s"), position = position_jitter()) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=86400, color = "purple") + 
  labs(title="Rides duration by customer type", 
       caption="From June 2022 to May 2023",
       x="Customer type",
       y="Ride duration (sec)") + 
  annotate("text", x=0.5, y=150000, label="86,400", color = "purple")
```

Unfortunately, when I run my visualization, I only have three dots, and therefore my visualization isn't trustworthy.

In fact, I've checked out, and my "ride_length" has only three rows.

There's any way to make a visualization with all of my 5674730 rows, with the ride_length included? Thank you again.

Comment: you need to call the `library(tidyverse)` and also use `mutate` in lowercase.

Comment: Hi! I used properly "mutate()": corrected_rides <- corrected_rides%>% 
+   mutate(ride_length = ended_at - started_at) But I hencounter this issue: In argument: `ride_length = ended_at - started_at`.
Caused by error in `ended_at - started_at`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: is there `Df` dataframe already available

Comment: Yes, that's "corrected_rides". May it has something to do with the format of ended_at/started_at? 2022-12-05 10:47:18

Comment: could you please show the actual data in the `Df`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are programming. You should  pay attention to cases.

I defined the cols as `datetime` so R understands I'm interested in the time, and not just the date. you can wrap this with `as_numeric()` to get only numbers, and obviously multiply if you need it in seconds (or divide for hours).

```
library(tidyverse)
    library(lubridate)
    df <- tibble(ended_at = c("2022-12-05 10:56:34", "2022-12-18 07:08:44", "2022-12-13 08:59:51"),
                 started_at = c("2022-12-05 10:47:18", "2022-12-18 06:42:33", "2022-12-13 08:47:45"))
    df |> mutate(ride_length = as_datetime(ended_at) - as_datetime(started_at))


      ended_at            started_at          ride_length   
      <chr>               <chr>               <drtn>        
    1 2022-12-05 10:56:34 2022-12-05 10:47:18  9.266667 mins
    2 2022-12-18 07:08:44 2022-12-18 06:42:33 26.183333 mins
    3 2022-12-13 08:59:51 2022-12-13 08:47:45 12.100000 mins
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! another question, can this chunk code you posted above be applicable to the entire columns?

Comment: Yes, It will iterate over all the rows. What sort of calculation would you need for other columns?

Comment: Basically I need to do the same operation (subtract values from one column to another) for all of the rows, in those same columns (ended_at/started_At). I'm new at this, and I thought that the operation would just be applied to those three first rows.

Comment: This will operate on your entire dataset. If you wish to operate on a subset, I would advise to create a designated subset dataset (df_subset, for example). Otherwise, As mentioned, this will operate on all the rows. Please feel free to check out the great resources at https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ :)

Comment: Hello again! I've tried to do a ggplot visualization of the ride_length with the code chunk that you've mentioned yesterday, but I just see those three valuesv of the tibble in the viz, and not the entire values. It's like ggplot it just have put into account the first three rows and forget about the rest. This is my code:

Comment: ggplot(data = ride_length) + geom_point(mapping = aes(x = "member_casual", y = duration_s), position = position_jitter()) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=86400, color = "red") + 
  labs(title="Rides duration by customer type", 
       caption="From June 2022 to May 2023",
       x="Customer type",
       y="Ride duration (sec)")
  annotate("text", x=0.5, y=150000, label="86,400", color = "red")

Comment: It is polite to thumb up a solution that was given to you. Otherwise, your code is not reproducible. Please delete your entire environment. then run the code again. if it doesnt run - it wont run for us either. `durations_s` for example. This is crucial: DELETE your environment >> create a working code example >> post it here >> ask your question. good luck!!

Comment: I didn't know how to put a thump up, sorry. I'll try again and I'll let you know. Thanks

Comment: Interesting use of base R's new pipe `|>` and not tidyverse's `%>%`. Why not just use base R's `transform` or `within` and not tidyverse's `mutate` and avoid the need to load the third-party package?!

Comment: I switched to |> because it has a nice "triangle" configuration with JetBrain Mono font. I load the tidyverse packages and personally believe it should be the default method to program in R, even for newebis. there is really no need to learn base R and then switch to tidyverse in my opinion